# How to number of map and reducer are defined for a query in hive

Tags: hive, hsqldb, hadoop2

I am new in hive and checking the execution plan (explain) for complex query which has sub query,joins with multiple tables and row_number with the aggregate functions.
Trying to figure out the allocation of map reduce task for the query. 
So I have few questions
1.Is allocation of Map-Reduce task are depend on size of table/number of joins ?
2.Every time I will get the same number of map and reduce?.
3. Can you please let me know the logic behind of allocations of map reduce for the queries.

Comment: Number of mappers is directly proportional to number of input splits. Reducers depends on the aggregation operations or joins which you perform on the data. If you are not doing Mapside join, each join will start a reducer.

Comment: @RohitNimmala How can I get how my query how many input slips are present

Comment: My answer is not fitting in the comment. Writing as the answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So, input split is a logical entity, and Block is a physical entity.  Let's say you're fetching data from HDFS, Map Reduce client calculates checks if the entire record resides in the same block, if some part of it is present in another block, the input split captures the location information, and byte offset of the next Block in order to complete the record. This usually happens in the multi-line record, input split is configured same as the size of block size. One Input split represents the size of data that will go in one mapper.